# Selenium WebDriver waitForText()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For AJAX application testing, is there a `waitForText()` method using Selenium WebDriver?

Basically, I need to test for refreshed/new element/text value post AJAX request.

Is an example of this available?

Answer (score 5):

Just do

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("idOfElement")));
```

where `10` is timeout for polling, [JavaDoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html).